# Have I got this IF Statement correct?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Based on [this snippet](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/), which checks the quantity in cart for MAX value:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['max_value'] = 10; // Maximum value
    return $args;
}
```

I'm trying to add a condition, i.e. if the item is `onsale` AND equals the value of `SESSION` variable:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) { 
    $onsale = $product->is_on_sale();
    if ( ( $_SESSION['odertype'] = 'local_delivery' ) && $onsale ) {
        $args['max_value'] = 10; // Maximum value
        return $args;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the 'AND' portion of the `IF` statement is not working, as the filter seems to be applied even if the session variable is NOT set!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `$_SESSION['odertype']`, should be `$_SESSION['ordertype']`. You are also ASSIGNING a value instead of testing it for [equivalency](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), try `==`.

If in doubt you can always use `var_dump($_SESSION)` to get all the values stored there.

Comment: @bas You also have the `return` inside your `if` condition - `$args` should *always* be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Burgi's answer, the correct snippet should be:

```
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) { 
    if (
        isset( $_SESSION['ordertype'] ) && // Never assume an array index exists
        $_SESSION['ordertype'] == 'local_delivery' && // Note == "same as" operator, not = "assign"
        $product->is_on_sale()
    ) {
        $args['max_value'] = 10; // Maximum value
    }

    // Always return args for other filters/sanity
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: The `isset` is a very good point. I missed that in my original read through of the question.